# Get Average number of records by unique Dates

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to find the average number of rows by unique dates against a single Type. Here is an example:

[image]

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AVERAGEX, passing a table that sums the number of records per day:

```
= AVERAGEX(
    SUMMARIZE(Table,
       Table[Types],
       "totalRecords", COUNT(Table[Records])
    ), [totalRecords])
```